Why would animation-timeline: view() not be working in production?
I have been scouring the internet to find ways to implement this animation feature on my portfolio website. The animation-timeline works as I intended in development, but when I run deploy (using Github Pages) it does not work on my production site. Also like to note that the Chrome devtools shows a slash through the animation-timeline attribute.
Here is the code I am using:
/* ------ SCROLL ANIMATIONS ------- */
.outer-shroud {
    animation: autoShowAnimation both;
    animation-timeline: view(100% 5%);
}

@keyframes autoShowAnimation {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(100px) scale(0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 0 1000px rgba(160, 158, 255, 0.944);
    } to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    }
}

<div className='outer-shroud' id='riddym' onClick={handleRiddymClick}>
     <div className='shroud'>
          <div className='project-title'>
               <div className='title'>
                    <h1>Riddym</h1>
                    <h3><span>July '24</span> — A familiar rhythm game, reimagined.</h3>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div className='arrow'>
               <i className="fa fa-arrow-right-long"></i>
          </div>
          <div className='project'>
               <div className='top-bar'>
                    <div className='dot-container'>
                         <div className='dot' id='dot-one'></div>
                         <div className='dot' id='dot-two'></div>
                         <div className='dot' id='dot-three'></div>
                    </div>
                         <div className='search-bar'></div>
               </div>
               <img src='/riddym/riddym-sample.png' alt='riddym'/>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>


Chrome devtools shows a slash through the animation-timeline attribute --> you have something else overriding the property
